# How quick sort huge mongoengine QuerySet in python

Tags: python, mongodb, sorting, python-2.7, mongoengine

I need make case and diacritic sensitive sort over whole collection, what mongoengine cannot do because mongodb has only case sensitive sort.

So I have an idea how to do that. Grab all entries in collection and then do my own unicode case insensitive sort in python. But there is problem with long delay because my collections are very huge. Is there way, how to do that quicker?

```
def initMongoengineData(model, criteria, only):
    if model == None:
        return

    print "-- starting DB query"
    print datetime.datetime.now()

    querySet = model.objects(**criteria).only(*only)

    print "-- data loaded"
    print datetime.datetime.now()

    return mongoengineQuerySetToList(querySet)

def mongoengineQuerySetToList(querySet):
    queryList = []
    dict = {}
    objDict = None
    objCounter = 0
    for obj in querySet:
        objCounter += 1
        dict = {}
        objDict = obj.to_mongo()
        for key in objDict:
            dict[key] = objDict[key]
        queryList.append(dict)

    print "-- structure for sorting is ready"
    print datetime.datetime.now()
    print "-- number of objects:"
    print objCounter
    queryList.sort(key=lambda x: x['surname'].lower())
    print "-- structure is sorted"
    print datetime.datetime.now()

    return queryList


model = Players  # mongoengine Document
criteria = {} 
only = ['surname']
datalist = initMongoengineData(model, criteria, only)
```

**Output:**

```
-- starting DB query
2013-08-24 16:45:57.721000
-- data loaded
2013-08-24 16:45:57.721000
-- structure for sorting is ready
2013-08-24 16:46:52.257000
-- number of objects:
82668
-- structure is sorted
2013-08-24 16:46:52.493000
```

Data loading and sorting after is very quick but preparing structure for sorting takes about **1 minute** what is very long delay. Can anybody help how to do this faster with so many entries in collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need sorting just by one field (`surname` for this example).

So base sorting (ordering) with mongoengine `model.objects(**criteria).only(*only).order_by('+surname')` see http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/guide/defining-documents.html#ordering.

But there are no easy way if you really need case insensetive sorting.

In you code there slowest block is `for obj in querySet`. In this block you get itemes from query set. You can try use `for obj in list(querySet)` to fetch all data at once, but I don't belive that it really increase performance.

The best way is add additional field with lower case. You also can try map reduce for this. I can't found how you can do this with agregation `project`.

Also case insensetive indexed will be on mongo 2.5.w (probably end of November) see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-90.